# STL list.push_front run times longer then what O(1) suggests

Tags: c++

I am testing for runtimes with visual studio 2015's Perftips and I noticed that when I use the STL "list" and access the push_front() function, it is running a 1000x's longer than it should and is also in O(n) time when it should be O(1).

For example:
I am creating a doubly linked list with a million random integers and it takes about 2000ms to add a single int value to the front of that million long list when I know it should be around 3ms.  I also noticed that the run times expand linearly with the size of the list I make, which is not what big-O predicts.

Here is the line of code I am testing:

*list.push_front(10);  // 10 is an arbitrary number*

I am also getting the same problem for singly linked lists and for O(1) vector functions.  Does anyone know what is going on?  Thanks for your time.

Side note:
I'm not sure if my hardware has anything to do with it but, I have a 2.4Ghz laptop i7 and half empty 700 gb hard drive with 8Gb of ram

Edit:
I am also running microsoft Excel, Adobe Reader, and chrome simultaneously while testing.  I closed the programs and it actually bumped up my run times by about 100ms oddly enough.

Comment: What else are you running on the machine?

Comment: microsoft Excel, Adobe Reader, and chrome

Comment: Why not close those down and see if that helps?

Comment: I closed the programs and it actually bumped up my run times by about 100ms

Comment: 1.   Can you show a complete program please.  2.  You are compiling with full optimization aren't you?  3.  How do you create singly linked list?  The standard library doesn't have one.

Comment: 4.  When you say it takes 2s to add an int to the front of the list and you are adding a million ints, do you mean you have a run time of 2E6 seconds == 23 days?

Comment: @MartinBonner AFAICT, `std::forward_list` is a singly linked list

Comment: its 2000m as in milli seconds.  So thats 2000x10^(-3) seconds which is equal to 2 seconds. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: `std::forward_list` - that's new!  Sorry.

Comment: Are you saying that it takes 2s to add all million elements?  If so, you are grossly underestimating how long adding an element will take.  To add an element, you have got to allocate memory for it, and that involves grabbing a mutex, and doing that in 2µs is quite good.  Grabbing a mutex in 3ns just ain't gonna happen.

Comment: no, it takes 2seconds to add a single element into the list that is a million elements long, making the end result a list that is a size million+1

Comment: You're doing 1,000,000 _allocations_. That may be the problem. You may have to consider using a custom allocator that goes to the heap only periodically, but has a sub-pool that it keeps track of. (i.e. something other than `std::allocate`, which is the default allocator for `std::list`)

Comment: My timing for 1,000,000 elements is 43 ms with optimization and 90 ms without. Seriously, something is really wrong with your system. Can you call up a utility to see what your CPU cores are doing [even when not running your program]? Try rebooting and then testing as the _first_ thing.

Comment: @Carry : We need to see the test program.  2s to add to the front of a std:list is seriously wierd.

Comment: @CraigEstey +1 I think you're right, I tried running the code on a different system and it runs in a blink of an eye.

Comment: That's why I suggested the reboot. Then, retest. If you still get bad results, use the task manager to look for runaway processes. You might have a virus or some such. Or, sometimes, a system just gets itself "into a state"

Comment: @CraigEstey I restarted and my processor is running around 5%  usage at start up and while executing the code, while my disk spikes to from ~14% to 100% when I hit that line.  I really hope its not a virus though, I don't see anything fishy going on the processes or when my computers performance when idling or gaming.

Comment: Hopefully, your code is running faster on the original machine after the reboot? Try the test a few times. It might be a transient background job (e.g. disk defrag, etc.) Otherwise, your program is compute bound. It shouldn't increase disk usage at all, _unless_ it's paging. Machine #1 has 8GB, how much does #2 have? Windows can consume a fair amount of RAM. When I benchmark, I usually have the program itself do 10 trials [you'd need to move your code to a sub-function] and take the one with the shortest time to eliminate transients.

Comment: Are you compiling with or without optimization?

Comment: @CraigEstey I think there's something just up with my system when running PerfTips to do timings.  I used the STL chrono instead on the original computer and got way smaller numbers that matched what big-O predicted and the data that got collected on the other computer.  I think i'm just going to stick with chrono from now on.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd do [and do myself, ala Richard's usage]. Sometimes, you have to get benchmarks on a running program "in the field", so you can't use an IDE. Also, if somebody said: "Okay, now port it to Linux/BSD/OSX", would you be freaking out? :-). Also, I'd cut down the iteration count to something small enough to fit in a timeslice (e.g. 1000 iterations will give you the same per-iteration number (i.e. 94 ns) as 1,000,000). Rerun [internally] a few times to prevent a span across a slice boundary and take the smallest [and/or average] number.

Comment: @CraigEstey Thanks Craig, i'm trying to get out of IDE's and using linux.  Anyways, thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The time O(1) means constant relative to size.  So to claim a slow down, you need to describe measurements at different sizes.

Whilst the `std::list` does adhere to this, neither the memory runtime (`new`, `delete`) nor the OS (`HeapAlloc`) do.

Try running release build (stl+ new faster)

Comment: Sounds like a good Idea, I understand what you are saying about adhering to big-O but could you give me a short run down on how to run the release build (stl+ new faster).  I'm not to use what you mean by that.

Comment: He means: "Create a release build, this will make both the STL and `new` faster"

Comment: @MartinBonner  ahh thank you

Answer (score 1):

Looks pretty O(1) to me:

```
#include <list>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>


void run_test(size_t items)
{
    std::list<int> mylist;
    std::cout << "testing " << std::setw(9) << std::right << items << " insertions: ";
    std::cout.flush();

    auto t0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    while(items) {
        mylist.push_front(10);
        --items;
    }
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto diff = t1 - t0;
    auto us = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(diff);
    std::cout << "took " << std::setw(9) << us.count() << "us to get to size " << std::setw(9) << mylist.size() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{

    for(int power = 1 ; power < 9 ; ++power)
    {
        run_test(std::pow(10, power));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

example results (clang, -O2, macbook pro on batteries)

```
testing        10 insertions: took         1us to get to size        10
testing       100 insertions: took         5us to get to size       100
testing      1000 insertions: took        60us to get to size      1000
testing     10000 insertions: took       582us to get to size     10000
testing    100000 insertions: took      5832us to get to size    100000
testing   1000000 insertions: took     66873us to get to size   1000000
testing  10000000 insertions: took    622131us to get to size  10000000
testing 100000000 insertions: took   6636721us to get to size 100000000
```

Comment: I might be mistaken, but think you have mistaken the difference between O(1) and O(n).  What it looks like to me is that you just created a list and took times how long it would take to create a list making it bigger each time.  That would of course take longer time as you increase the size which would be O(n), not O(1).  Again I could be mistaken on what you meant to show me.  The question was, if I wanted to add a single element to a list, it takes much longer to add that single element to a list size million then it would a list of size 10, when it really shouldn't.

Comment: @Carry the standard mandates that each insertion is O(1) i.e. the time taken to do one insertion is not dependent on the size of the container. performing a million inserts should take ~1 million times as long as 1 insert, no matter how many items are in the list. This test confirms that. Inserting 10^8 items takes 10 times as long as inserting 10^7. Therefore each insert is O(1).

Comment: @Carry It is timing *all* the insertions. Divide the time by the number of insertions to get your O(1).

Answer (score 0):

Solved by @CraigEstey.

There's just something wrong with my system when using PerfTips.  I ran the code using the chrono stl and got way different data that matched what big-O predicted.

Thanks for the feedback guys and gals.